# Where or how to store the access token from Laravel passport in react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, token, laravel-passport

I am aware that there are similar questions to mine, but I would like to know what the correct approach would be for my case.

I am trying to build a web-app using Laravel (for the backend) and React (frontend).

A user can login with his user name and password, whereupon he receives a personal access token. On every login, all tokens for that user that haven't expired yet are deleted and a new one is created.
Now I asked myself where to store this token so that it is not persistent and just lasts for the current session.

If a user logs out, the token is deleted. But what if a user does not manually log out and just closes the browser? The token would still be valid until its expire date, so that would be a problem.

Laravel and React are both on the same server and React is added to Laravel if that changes anything.

I'm just experimenting, but nevertheless I'd like to know how one would do this and hope someone could explain to me how it's done right.

Comment: Passport has a built in middleware to take care of this for you. Check the [Consuming your API with Javascript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) section of the documentation.